# Specializing constructor of class template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to specialize a constructor of a class template. This doesn't work:

```
template<typename T>
struct One {};

template<typename T>
struct Two {};

template<template<typename> class T, template<typename> class U>
struct Three : public T<Three<T, U>>, public U<Three<T, U>> {};

template<typename T> struct Four;

template<typename T>
struct Four
{
   Four();
};

template<template<typename> class T, template<typename> class U>
Four<Three<T, U>>::Four() {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Four<Three<One, Two> > obj;
}
```

but changing the class template definition to this works:

```
template<typename T> struct Four;

template<template<typename> class T, template<typename> class U>
struct Four<Three<T, U>>
{
   Four();
};

template<template<typename> class T, template<typename> class U>
Four<Three<T, U>>::Four() {}
```

This seems like I'm specializing the entire class template. However I want to specialize only the constructor as in the code above - the one that doesn't work. Why can't I specialize the constructor of `Four` for just `Three` (I'm not changing the signature of the ctor of the class template)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You must specialize the whole class. But.. you can use inheritance as a work around:

```
#include <iostream>

class something {};

template <typename T> class hidden_base {
    public:    hidden_base() {a = 1;}
    protected: int a;
};

template<> class hidden_base<something> {
    public:    hidden_base() {a = 2;}
    protected: int a;
};

template <typename T>
class your_class : public hidden_base<T> {
public:
    void lots();
    void of();
    void other();
    void member();
    void functions();
    void here();

    void show_a() {std::cout << hidden_base<T>::a << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    your_class<long>().show_a();
    your_class<int>().show_a();
    your_class<something>().show_a();
}
```

This will print:

```
1
1
2
```

Comment: Ya this'll work and so does `template<> Four<Three<One, Two>>::Four() {}`. But what is preventing me from doing the one that doesn't work. I'm not changing the constructor in any way and unless I'm doing that I should not specialize the entire class (if i want `Four(const std::string&)` for the specialized case for instance i understand). So could you tell me what standard rule applies to this (restricts the usage in the mentioned fashion)?